# how do I fix full text search for 3 characters?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have used full text search mysql. My code is
    select * from uh_property WHERE match(fieldname) against('serach_word')

Now when i type word of three character search record is not displayed. For example i have record with name 'eco'. When i type eco in text box for search no record displayed.

I found that minimum character for full text search is 4. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html). You first need to change 
`ft_min_word_len` (or `innodb_ft_min_token_size` for InnoDB tables) and then rebuild the fulltext search indexes.

Comment: Thank you Yuval F! I checked the site before as well i can't do this for live site as the server is not for single site. Any solution for this?

Comment: I am missing something here. Could you please explain your configuration? Do you have control of the mysql server?

Comment: Yes I used 
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3 and it worked for local. Now I need to do this in live server. Will that affect server or create any problem? Yes i have control for mysql server for live.

Comment: I think rebuilding the indexes will probably slow down your live server. If possible, I would divert live traffic away from the server, change the variable, rebuild the index and then return the server to be live.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yuval. One thing is that i could not get the my.cnf file? Could you please tell how and where to access this file in server. My server is plesk. I tried to find out how and where to get this file but did not find the solution. Yes I have come to know this file exists in /home/mydir/ or etc/my.cnf but do not know how to see these folder and the files.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with plesk. In a vanilla linux server, I would use something like 'locate my.cnf' to find the file. I glanced at the plesk documentation, and there seems to be some kind of administrator control panel you may use. Maybe you should post this as a separate question in ServerFault. Good luck.