# Mysql fulltext search result empty for some special words

Tags: mysql

I had a question about mysql fulltext search. I do a fulltext search on my table, when I search the word start with `'ra'` or `'rb'`, `'rc'`, I can get result from mysql, but when the searched word start with `'rd'` or `'re'` , I get empty result. 
My table and sqls as below :

```
create table test_2_field (
                           id int(10) auto_increment not null primary key,
                           article varchar(200),
                           body text,
                           FULLTEXT KEY `article` (`article`,`body`)
                          ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


insert into test_2_field(article,body) values('hehe','ra rb rc rd re rf');
```

When I search the word start with 'rc'(or 'ra' or 'rb') , it works.

```
select * from test_2_field where match(article,body) against('+rc*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

But When I these , I got empty retry.

```
select * from test_2_field where match(article,body) against('+re*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

select * from test_2_field where match(article,body) against('+rd*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I think `'rd'`, `'re'` is not a key word for mysql , and I have no idea about it. 
If someone know about this please help me , thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I fix full text search for 3 characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130492/how-do-i-fix-full-text-search-for-3-characters). By default, MySQL FullText indexes ignore words of 3 characters or less.

Comment: hi RandomSeed , I had set ft_min_word_len=1 . In this case , I can search "rc" , it's already below 2 characters. The search failed only when the key word is "rd" or "re".

Comment: Yeah I must be blind, I missed that. Sorry about that.

Comment: "re" and "rd" are default stopwords, ignored by fulltext indexes by default. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: Thank you RandomSeed , That's very helpful. Thank you very much