# Mysql boolean full text search using plus icon and at the rate icon

Tags: mysql, boolean

I have getting unexpected results from mysql boolean search.

```
select kapp_full_name from kols where match(kapp_full_name) against ('+Xin +Yu' in boolean mode);
```

If I have a record "Xin Xin Yu" in kols table it must be matched right? But it is not happening. Is there any rule like the search string minimum character 3 or something?

I have also tried

```
select kapp_full_name from kols where match(kols.kapp_full_name) against ('"xin yu*" @3' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

but no result. It is working for many.But why not for this record. Can you please help

Comment: *"Is there any rule like the search string minimum character 3 or something?"* Yes, there is, see [how do I fix full text search for 3 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1130492)